# 'Large Type' in Mac like in Address Book application

Tags: mac

Is there a way in Mac or an application that would give the text on the screen in the same way as [here](http://cl.ly/1T7y) which would be very helpful during presentations. I could find this feature marked as 'Large Type' only in address book in the Mac .

I had some other setting on my Mac to show on the screen if I ever pressed CapsLock or Ctrl or Cmd key (I cannot find it now ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Quicksilver for this. There's an old article talking about how to [use Quicksilver for timed reminders](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/02/06/quicksilver-tip-timed-reminders/) that uses the Large Type feature. Quicksilver has become more and more elusive over the past few years but it looks like it's still alive with a March 2010 download link for b58 at [GitHub](http://github.com/tiennou/blacktree-alchemy/downloads).

[image: Quicksilver interface]

[image]