# "Large Type" function from OS X command line

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to call this function: ['Large Type' in Mac like in Address Book application](https://superuser.com/questions/156063/large-type-in-mac-like-in-address-book-application)

from the command line?

Comment: You need a GUI anyway, is using QuickSilver not an option? See also: [Quicksilver Large Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234686/quicksilver-large-type)

Comment: Address Book's AppleScript dictionary does not support this functionality directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Growl](http://growl.info/) to display your text as a notification. You can use Growl's AppleScript API as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/225097/22317) using `osascript` from the command line to specify a specific display style.

Growl display styles are basically HTML and CSS, so you can easily create your own and customize its look to be "large type" instead of a regular notification. [Check out some third party styles](http://growl.info/styles) for inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice utility called 'LargeType2' that add a 'Service' menu item to display such large texts:

Homepage and download link: http://blyt.net/algrtepy2e/

[image: official screenshot]

Comment: This tool does work, but it can't be launched from the command line which is what the original question asked for.

Comment: As of 2021, the tool does support the ability to draw text from the command line.